# Show that the $n^{th}$ order differential equation $f^{(n)}-G(f,f^{(1)},...,f^{(n-1)})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be $n$ times differentiable and let $G: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Show that the $n^{th}$ order differential equation $f^{(n)}-G(f,f^{(1)},...,f^{(n-1)})=0$ can be reduced to a system of $n$ coupled first order differential equation

### My attempt:

Let:

$$x_1 = f$$
$$x_2 = f^{(1)}$$
$$x_n = f^{(n-1)}$$

Then,

$$x_1'= x_2$$
$$x_2'= x_3$$
$$x_{n-1}'= x_n$$

Not sure where to go with this...

Comment: Show *what* about "the $n^{th}$ order differential equation $f^{(n)}-G(f,f^(1),...,f^{(n-1)})=0$"? You just have the equation and do not say what you want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there. Let $x_1=f$, $x_2=f'$ and so on.
Then we can rewrite the problem as
$$x_1'=x_2$$
$$x_2'=x_3$$
$$\vdots$$
$$x_n'=G(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$$
which is a system of coupled first order differential equations.

Comment: I hope I got your question right... it just seems you nearly had it.